# How to display different colours in a select box for different options

Tags: html, css

I have part of a code where it displays a Multi Select box and displays the options depending on the if statement:

```
$moduleSELECT = '<select name="moduletextarea" id="moduleselect" size="10">'.PHP_EOL;      

if($modulenum == 0){

$moduleSELECT .= "<option disabled='disabled' value=''>No Modules currently on this Course</option>";   


}else{   

while ( $currentmodstmt->fetch() ) {

$moduleSELECT .= sprintf("<option disabled='disabled' value='%s'>%s - %s</option>", $dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName) . PHP_EOL; 
}

}

$moduleSELECT .= '</select>';
```

Now from doing some research on the internet I think it is bad practice to include  tags inside option tags. So my question is that if the if statement is true where number of records in 0, how can I display the text for `"<option disabled='disabled' value=''>No Modules currently on this Course</option>";` in red colour and if the else statement is met how can I display these options `sprintf("<option disabled='disabled' value='%s'>%s - %s</option>", $dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName) . PHP_EOL;` in black colour text?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set a css style to the select (if there are no options), in this case `color: red;` 
you can also have different colors for the options as well, just set different colors on each option. example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kennypu/CP8Xf/1/

Comment: Upvote and best answer, did not know you can put a class in option tag but as you shown you can

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can style individual `<option>` tags with CSS, but you could style the entire `<select>` as @kennypu points out.

Another way to achieve the results you want with a better/more intuative UI might be to only output the `<select>` tag when you actually have data to put inside it.  When `$modulenum == 0` maybe you should just output some different HTML that you can style properly.

HTML

```
<div class='no-data'>No Modules currently on this Course</div>
```

CSS

```
.no-data{
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```